# Can I easily put an SSD in an ASUS G75, and which ones?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, upgrade, laptop-repair

I've been out of the hardware game for a while.  I'm looking to buy a new laptop, but even the gaming laptops mostly come with a 5400 RPM HDD.  I've got my eye on some variant of the ASUS G75 but I'm wondering if I can replace the HDD with an SSD and if so, are there any particular models/connectors/interfaces I can and cannot use?  Also, how easy is it to do?

**update** I purchased the g75vx-bhi7n11.  Here is a screenshot of disk management. Device manager only shows one HDD.

[image]

Comment: because your model only has one hard drive, and large ssd's are expensive but games take lots of space, i would recommend a hybrid drive.
http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/laptop-hard-drives/laptop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Asus g75's use two hard-drives. If this is the case with your model i would buy one SSD for your OS and the other HDD i would leave for your games. Your computer uses 2.5" standard size internal hard-drives.If your model only has one hard drive, and large ssd's are expensive but games take lots of space, i would recommend a hybrid drive. http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/laptop-hard-drives/laptop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/

Comment: Added exact model and screenshot of Disk Management.

Comment: Accepted mostly based on your latest comment to OP.  Perhaps update this answer to include that link and recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

SSD drives use the standard SATA interface. They are the same across the board. Just make sure you get a 2.5" drive. As for the second part of your question...

It depends on the complexity of the enclosure and your skill in taking apart and reassembling electronic devices. I'd say anyone can do it. Just make sure you memorize, or even take pictures of how things are connected including wires and screws.

Comment: Added exact model and screenshot of Disk Management.